# Increase uploaded file size limit in django heroku gunicorn

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

When i am trying to upload a file of more than 1mb using ajax/jquery. Server is throwing error though everything is working perfectly on localhost.I am using heroku to host application and procfile is written to use gunicorn as http server.How do i configure server to accept every file of every size?

```
Procfile
web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I'm trying with this following configuration: gunicorn app.wsgi --timeout 300 --limit-request-line 8190 --limit-request-fields 200 --limit-request-field_size 8190 --keep-alive 5 --log-file -

Comment: This might help: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-reduce-a-large-heroku-compiled-slug-size